# NASM Not Running Correctly in C

Tags: c, assembly, segmentation-fault, nasm

I wrote a NASM file in x64:

```
section .text
        global _start
_start:
        jmp j
r:
        pop rsi
        mov al, 1d
        mov dil, 1d
        mov dl, 13d
        syscall

        xor eax, eax
        mov al, 60d
        syscall

j:      call r
        db "Hello World!",10
```

Compiled with:

```
nasm -f elf64 -o TEMP.o file.asm
ld -s -o exec TEMP.o
```

Shellcode:

```
\xeb\x10\x5e\xb0\x01\x40\xb7\x01\xb2\x0d\x0f\x05\x31\xc0\xb0\x3c\x0f\x05\xe8\xeb\xff\xff\xff\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x20\x57\x6f\x72\x6c\x64\x21\x0a
```

When I execute `./exec`, it prints "Hello World" like it should. However, when I put it in the following C file, it gives me a segmentation fault.

Also, when I change:

```
unsigned char shellcode[] = ...
```

to

```
unsigned char * shellcode = ...
```

I get no output whatsoever.

C Source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned char shellcode[] = "\xeb\x10\x5e\xb0\x01\x40\xb7\x01\xb2\x0d\x0f\x05\x31\xc0\xb0\x3c\x0f\x05\xe8\xeb\xff\xff\xff\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x20\x57\x6f\x72\x6c\x64\x21\x0a";

int main(){
        printf("Shellcode Length (Bytes): %d\n", strlen(shellcode));
        ((void(*)(void))shellcode)();
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have figured it out. Only recently have I moved to Crunchbang. I now have to specify `-z execstack` for it to work. Thanks to anyone who actually tried to give me an answer!